# Jenkins me devuleve este error> ImportError: Import by filename is not supported

Tags: python, jenkins

MI problema es el siguiente: Estoy intentando integrar jenkins con mi proyecto python, donde ya le he podido configurar algunas cosas como el pep8 y pylint, pero estoy intentando ahora con los test a travez de unittest. Esto en lo que he puesto en la configuracion:

python -m unittest **dtzerp/apps/rh/controlasistencia** > *build/pytest/unittest.xml*

Donde lo que esta en negritas es donde se encuetra mi archivo test.py que tienes las pruebas implementadas y lo que esta en cursiva es donde supuestamente se me guardara el .xml con los resultados de las prubas, pero al construir el build se genera este error y ademas cuando voy al archivo .xml me dice que esta vacio.

Alguin me podria ayudar con esto?

```
Started by user Admin
Building in workspace /opt/jenkins-2.46.2-0/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home  /workspace/VERSAT_ERP > /opt/jenkins-2.46.2-0/git/bin/git rev-parse --is-  inside-work-tree # timeout=10 Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> /opt/jenkins-2.46.2-0/git/bin/git config remote.origin.url  http://admin@gitlab.datazucar.cu/python/Versat-ERP.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from http://mario.garcia@gitlab.datazucar.cu  /python/Versat-ERP.git > /opt/jenkins-2.46.2-0/git/bin/git --version #   timeout=10 using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials > /opt/jenkins-2.46.2-0 /git/bin/git fetch --tags --progress      http://mario.garcia@gitlab.datazucar.cu/python/Versat-ERP.git +refs/heads  /*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> /opt/jenkins-2.46.2-0/git/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin  /develop^{commit} # timeout=10
> /opt/jenkins-2.46.2-0/git/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin  /develop^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision de3830e8dd4a7afb471e2f10a81af2552991a4e0    (refs/remotes/origin/develop)
Commit message: "Mario --- Subiendo archivo test.py para probar  integracion con el jenkins"
> /opt/jenkins-2.46.2-0/git/bin/git config core.sparsecheckout #    timeout=10
> /opt/jenkins-2.46.2-0/git/bin/git checkout -f  de3830e8dd4a7afb471e2f10a81af2552991a4e0
> /opt/jenkins-2.46.2-0/git/bin/git rev-list   de3830e8dd4a7afb471e2f10a81af2552991a4e0 # timeout=10
Run condition [Execute Shell] enabling prebuild for step [Invoke Ant]
Run condition [Execute Shell] enabling prebuild for step [Invoke Ant]
Run condition [Execute Shell] enabling prebuild for step [Invoke Ant]
Run condition [Execute Shell] enabling prebuild for step [Invoke Ant]
[VERSAT_ERP] $ /bin/sh -xe /opt/jenkins-2.46.2-0/apache-tomcat   /temp/CommandInterpreterCondition2731773612737679824.sh
+ pep8 --max-line-length=120 dtzerp/apps/admin/
Run condition [Execute Shell] preventing perform for step [Invoke Ant]
[VERSAT_ERP] $ /bin/sh -xe /opt/jenkins-2.46.2-0/apache-tomcat  /temp/CommandInterpreterCondition22160854813579713.sh
+ pylint --output-format=parseable --reports=y dtzerp/apps/admin/   --disable=w0611,w0614,f0401,cd301 --max-line-length=120 --rcfile=build/pylint  /pylint.cfg
No config file found, using default configuration
Run condition [Execute Shell] preventing perform for step [Invoke Ant]
[VERSAT_ERP] $ /bin/sh -xe /opt/jenkins-2.46.2-0/apache-tomcat /temp/CommandInterpreterCondition3358860767606403541.sh
+ sloccount --duplicates --wide --details dtzerp/apps/admin/
Run condition [Execute Shell] enabling perform for step [Invoke Ant]
[VERSAT_ERP] $ /opt/jenkins-2.46.2-0/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/tools   /hudson.tasks.Ant_AntInstallation/Ant_1.10.1/bin/ant
Buildfile: /opt/jenkins-2.46.2-0/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace  /VERSAT_ERP/build.xml

init:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
[VERSAT_ERP] $ /bin/sh -xe /opt/jenkins-2.46.2-0/apache-tomcat /temp/CommandInterpreterCondition5200661985837307314.sh
+ python -m unittest dtzerp/apps/rh/controlasistencia
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/__main__.py", line 12, in <module>
main(module=None)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
self.parseArgs(argv)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 149, in parseArgs
self.createTests()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 158, in createTests
self.module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 130, in  loadTestsFromNames
suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 91, in  loadTestsFromName
module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
Run condition [Execute Shell] preventing perform for step [Invoke Ant]
[WARNINGS] Parsing warnings in files 'build/pep8/pep8.xml' with parser  Pep8
[WARNINGS] Searching for all files in /opt/jenkins-2.46.2-0/apps/jenkins /jenkins_home/workspace/VERSAT_ERP that match the pattern build/pep8/pep8.xml
[WARNINGS] Parsing 1 file in /opt/jenkins-2.46.2-0/apps/jenkins /jenkins_home/workspace/VERSAT_ERP
[WARNINGS] Successfully parsed file /opt/jenkins-2.46.2-0/apps/jenkins /jenkins_home/workspace/VERSAT_ERP/build/pep8/pep8.xml with 940 unique   warnings and 0 duplicates.
[WARNINGS] Parsing warnings in files 'build/pylint/pylint.xml' with  parser PyLint
[WARNINGS] Searching for all files in /opt/jenkins-2.46.2-0/apps/jenkins /jenkins_home/workspace/VERSAT_ERP that match the pattern build/pylint /pylint.xml
[WARNINGS] Parsing 1 file in /opt/jenkins-2.46.2-0/apps/jenkins /jenkins_home/workspace/VERSAT_ERP
[WARNINGS] Successfully parsed file /opt/jenkins-2.46.2-0/apps/jenkins /jenkins_home/workspace/VERSAT_ERP/build/pylint/pylint.xml with 2933 unique   warnings and 0 duplicates.
[WARNINGS] Parsing warnings in console log with parser Pep8
[WARNINGS] Parsing warnings in console log with parser PyLint
[WARNINGS] Computing warning deltas based on reference build #88
Recording test results
Build step 'Publish JUnit test result report' changed build result to    UNSTABLE
[SLOCCount] Report successfully processed and all data stored
Finished: UNSTABLE
```